# Reactjs-rails troubles with pre-rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, coffeescript, reactjs, react-rails

I use `react-rails` gem and met specific trouble: prerendering doesn't work. I've wrote the code, but send an exception to me:

```
Encountered error "ReferenceError: Terminal is not defined" when prerendering Terminal with {}
```

Here is the sources of my code:

```
#= require jquery
#= require jquery_ujs
#= require turbolinks
#= require react
#= require react_ujs
#= require components
#= require_tree .
```

`components.js.coffee`

```
#= require_tree ./components
```

`terminal.js.jsx.coffee`

```
Terminal = React.createClass
  render: ->
    `<div>fffs</div>`
```

And the view:

```
= react_component 'Terminal', {}, prerender: true
```

I'm using default `react-rails` settings and don't know what's going wrong (I can't understand why react can't find a `Terminal` component).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your using `prerender: true` for server rendering, therefore your need to make sure your component is **globally accessible**:

```
@Terminal = React.createClass
  render: ->
    `<div>fffs</div>`
```

Read more about it on [react-rails documentation](https://github.com/reactjs/react-rails#server-rendering).